# Laravel Class 'Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, thermal-printer

I am building an application that uses thermal printer and I found the Mike42/Escpos library.

I am using laravel for my application

I have installed the library in my application

but I am getting the following error.

> Class 'Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector' not found

Composer.json

```
{
   "require": {
       "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.11",
       "mike42/escpos-php": "^3.0"
   }
}
```

Web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
Route::get('/', function () {
   $connector = new FilePrintConnector("XP-58IIH");
   $printer = new Printer($connector);
   $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
   $printer -> cut();
   $printer -> close();
});
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @jeto the mike42 library is on the vendor folder. Where should I include vender/autoload.php

Comment: @jeto @nnam4x this is not required since Laravel does this in the `public/index.php`.

Comment: Oops, missed that this was Laravel even though it's literally in the title. @nnam4x How did you install the library? Did you run `composer require <package>` or did you just edit composer.json? If you did you'll need to run `composer install` first.

Comment: I tried reproducing this, but it is working for me fine. Just be sure to do as @Jeto asked.